# How to onClick in Ajax Process

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have added html code in ajax process,but I have faced problem when using onclick function in there.

The expected result will show "12". 
But,the problem I got "undefined" val.

```
function getValue(){
     var val= $(this).find('.imageClass').val();
     alert(val);                
  }

function getImage(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'image.php?id='+ID,
        async: false,
        beforeSend: function(x) {
            if(x && x.overrideMimeType) {
                x.overrideMimeType("application/j-son;charset=UTF-8");
            }
        },
        dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){                                                               
            var html = '';      
            }

            html+='<div onClick="getValue()"><input class="imageClass" type="hidden" value="12"/>'+
                      '<img src="img/'+ID+'.png" style="width: 200px;"></div>'+
                   '</div>';             

                $('.content').html(html);
            }           
        });
}
```

Comment: Code you posted should not work at all as there is excess "}" after `var html = '';`

Comment: `console.log(this);`

Comment: Oh,I have deleted half code because too long,but here just focus on onclick function when inside ajax function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a custom function with even delegation like:

```
$(document).on(".ToClick",function getValue() {

//action to do here

});
```

Your HTML

```
html+='<div class="ToClick"><input class="imageClass" type="hidden" value="12"/>'+
                      '<img src="img/'+ID+'.png" style="width: 200px;"></div>'+
                   '</div>';
```

Or send this into HTML function

```
 html+='<div onClick="getValue(this)"><input class="imageClass" type="hidden" value="12"/>'+
                      '<img src="img/'+ID+'.png" style="width: 200px;"></div>'+
                   '</div>';
```

And the function should be:

```
function getValue(e){
     var val= $(e).find('.imageClass').val();
     alert(val);                
  }
```

Note: the inline function is not recomemded, use event delegation instead.

Answer (score 0):

You must attach an eventhandler dinamically using on

```
$("selector").on("event",function getValue() {

//action to do here

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the jQuery Deferred Object and outsource the success function.
That onclick Event is not being parsed.

```
function getValue(){
     var val= $(this).find('.imageClass').val();
     alert(val);                
  }

function getImage(){
    $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
        url: 'image.php?id='+ID, //Wherever that ID comes from
        async: false,
        beforeSend: function(x) {
            if(x && x.overrideMimeType) {
                x.overrideMimeType("application/j-son;charset=UTF-8");
           }
       },
       dataType: "json"      
       }).done(
       function(data){
        var html = $('<div><input class="imageClass" type="hidden"    value="12"/>'+
                      '<img src="img/'+ID+'.png" style="width: 200px;">    </div>'+
                  '</div>');             
            html.find('input').on('click', getValue);
                $('.content').html(html);

        };
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try also this way.. :)

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the only problem, but it is a problem: your `onclick` handler looks like this:

```
onClick="getValue()"
```

Within `getValue` you are assuming that `this` is set to the `div` that was clicked, but this is not the case.  Within the context of the code in `onclick`, `this` is set to that `div`, but once the function is called, that context is lost.  This would work:

```
onClick="getValue.call(this)"
```